# How to write keystroke data to excel file in python?

Tags: python, keystroke

I have written a simple program that captures keystroke data. I created two functions (on_Press and on_release), I want to write all captured keystrokes data from on_press() & on_release() to a new excel file every time the enter key is pressed.

But after executing below code, the program is only writing the "Enter" key data and ignoring the rest.

Any ideas, please?

Thanks

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile



key_pressed = [0]
key_press_time = [0]
key_released = [0]
key_release_time = [0]


def on_press(key):
    global key_pressed, key_press_time, key_released, key_release_time
    key_pressed = key
    key_press_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%M:%S.%f')

    return key_pressed, key_press_time


def on_release(key):
    global key_pressed, key_press_time, key_released, key_release_time
    key_released = key
    key_release_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%M:%S.%f')

    key_dict = {'Key_Pressed':[key_pressed],
                'Key_Press_Time':[key_press_time],
                'Key_Released':[key_released],
                'Key_Release_Time':[key_release_time]}

    kd = pd.DataFrame(key_dict)

    print(kd)


    if key == Key.enter:
        writer = ExcelWriter('KeystrokeData.xlsx')
        kd.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
        writer.save()
        # Stop listener
        return False




# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: What is the problem? Just write them.

Comment: I did write it using ; writer = ExcelWriter('KeystrokeData.xlsx')
        kd.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
        writer.save() 

But its only saving the enter key attribute and ignoring the rest